# Visual Studio 2015 Cannot Connect to SharePoint 2016

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sharepoint-2016

I have spun up a Windows Server 2012 box with SQL Server 2016 and SharePoint 2016. I have loaded Visual Studio 2015 Professional and the Office Tools for Visual Studio 2015. When I expand the Server Explorer and click on the "Add SharePoint Connection" icon, or right click the "SharePoint Connections branch and select "Add Connection" I get a messagebox back reporting "A task was canceled."

I have seen posts that describe a similar problem with VS2010 and SP2013, and these seem to pretty consistently point to the user having changed the time zone after installation of SP and/or Visual Studio. I never changed the time zone on this box. It is set to the default of UTC.

Can someone help me with this before I pull out what little hair I have left?